# Which grandfathers was King David afraid of?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Tehillim 19:14 says:

> גם מזדים, חשוך עבדך--    אל-ימשלו-בי אז איתם
>
> Also from zeidis keep your servant away, let them not rule over me

Who were these grandfathers who wanted to rule over King David, and as King of Israel with an army at his disposal, why was he so afraid of a group of presumably old men?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ruth 4:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t2904.htm) indicates that David's grandfather was a worker. David, as king, was trying to make sure the workers didn't have any control over him. That is, he was anti-union.

Answer (score 4):

"Zeidi's" is the name of a traditional Jewish food, consisting of chicken nuggets in a spicy sauce whose recipe is as closely guarded as that of the ketoret. In our generation, the keepers of this recipe have a shop near Yeshiva University in New York City. Not being subject to the restriction on honey like the ketoret, "Zeidis" is irresistible, but can lead to heartburn. David is praying for relief from this heartburn.

> Even from Zeidis spare your servant, that it may not control me, then I will be healthy

Answer (score 1):

He was most probably scared of Eglon Melech Moav his ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Dovid Hamelech was lactose intolorent. Yes.

That explains why he wanted to stay away from **Zitis**, not Zeidis.

Comment: This is also why he died on Shavuos. He had too much dairy that day.